# How to get a time series based on a spectrogram in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, spectrogram

I have a time series and generate its spectrogram in Python with matplotlib.pyplot.specgram.
After I make some analysis and changes I need to convert the spectrogram back into time series. 
Is there any function in matplotlib or in other library that I can use directly? Or if not, could you please elaborate on which direction I should work on?

Your warm help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] for what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9877/reconstruction-of-audio-signal-from-spectrogram?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

One thing commonly done (for example in the source separation community) is to use the phase data of the original signal (before transformation where applied to it) - the result is much better than null or random phase, and not so far from algorithms aiming at reconstructing the phase information from scratch.

A classic reconstruction algorithm is Griﬃn&Lim's, described in the paper "Signal estimation from modiﬁed short-time Fourier transform". This is an iterative algorithm, each iteration requires a full STFT / inverse STFT, which makes it quite costly.

This problem is indeed an active area of research, a search for STFT + reconstruction + magnitude will yield plenty of papers aiming at improving on Griffin&Lim in terms of signal quality and/or computational efficiency.

You can find detailed dicussion here[Thread on DSP Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3406/reconstruction-of-audio-signal-from-its-absolute-spectrogram?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib is a library for plotting data. Generally if you're trying to do any  computation you'd use a library suited for that.

`numpy` is a very popular library for doing numerical computation in Python. It just so happens they have a fairly extensive set of `fft` and `ifft` methods.

I would [check them out here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.fft.html) and see if they can solve your problem.